# Cannot boot into newly installed Ubuntu 20.04 from GRUB

Tags: grub2, brightness, acpi, amd-ryzen, mouse-pointer

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside windows 10 inside my MS1 modern 14 B4MW (AMD Ryzen 5 4500u, integrated graphics, 8GB RAM) using a USB. When trying to install Ubuntu, I was getting  some error messages. [ACPI BIOS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJN0x.jpg)

So installed Ubuntu using the safe graphics option. The next steps went smoothly and I chose to install  Ubuntu alongside Windows and I also checked the option to do updates while installing. After the installation I went into the BIOS and changed my boot order to boot into Ubuntu. Now when I power on my laptop I can see the GRUB menu, but when I choose the first option to boot into Ubuntu, the laptop just freezes and nothing happens. I can still access Ubuntu through the Advanced Options and then selecting the recover mode, but the mouse pointer feels sluggish and i cannot control the screen brightness neither through the keyboard buttons nor through the brightness slider.
Please help me. What do i need to do to directly boot into Ubuntu without going to Advanced Options and how can i change my screen brightness?

Comment: Did you check for any firmware updates for your machine?  Those may fix all sorts of problems.  There are many acpi options, but while some may help, they may also reduce your machine's capabililties, e.g. acpi=0 may turn off multi core use.

Comment: i solved the isuue. All i needed to do was add 'iommu=softt' to the boot parameters.

Comment: You may answer your own question, and after a few days, accept the answer, helping others and gaining some reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution on the garuda linux forum. When i added 'iommu=soft' to the boot paramaters, the acpi errors went away and i was able to successfully install Ubuntu.

https://forum.garudalinux.org/t/cant-boot-on-integrated-radeon-gpu/14890/18